# Simple Rails 3 Association - has_many, belongs_to, and has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I'm new to rails and trying to understand exactly how to do associations and if I've done it correctly.  I've read the [rails guide on associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and searched the web and found a number of resources, but I am just not sure.

You can see my project here: majorfinder.com  On my app there will be majors, schools, and careers.  I want to be able to add reviews for each.  Since I'm just starting out I'm just beginning with adding reviews for majors.

Here are my associations:

models/review.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_and_belongs_to_many :majors
```

models/user.rb

```
has_many :reviews
```

models/major.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :reviews
```

My first question is, does this look like a good way to create the associations?

I understand how to do a simple association in the majors controller:

```
@reviews = Review.includes(:user)
```

and with that I can show the review my major controller:

```
<div class="row">
  <% @reviews.each do |review| %>
    <div>
      <h3><%= link_to review.review,
        :controller => "reviews", :action => "show", :id => review.id %></h3>
      <small>Posted on <%= review.created_at %> by
        <a href="#"><%= review.user.profile_name %></a></small>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

but I'm not sure how to make this connect to the specific major I'm looking at.

My review database schema has review(text), user_id(integer), and major_id(integer).

The last question is how do I post a review inside the major controller show page with that specific major connected to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, are you sure you want a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between `reviews` and `majors`? I would assume that each review only applies to one particular major (or school/career), if that's the case it's a one-to-many relationship and you'll want to use `has_many` and `belongs_to`.

Secondly, given you'll eventually want to add reviews to your other models as well, you may want to make it a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), which will allow you to use the same `review` model for all three other models. To do that you'll want to change your associations to the following:

```
# In review.rb
belongs_to :reviewable, polymorphic: true

# In major.rb (and later also in school.rb and career.rb)
has_many :reviews, as: :reviewable
```

You'll also need to change your review model then so that instead of having a `major_id` property, it has a `reviewable_id` `integer` property and a `reviewable_type` `string` property.

In terms of how you'll want to display them, you'll probably want to include the `review` and `user` models when you initially load your major (assuming you want to show all the reviews, although you may eventually want to look at splitting them up into pages if there are a lot of them):

```
# In majors_controller.rb (or whatever it's named)
def show
  @major = Major.includes(:reviews => :user).find(params[:id])
  ...
```

Then in your view, you can user the `reviews` method of `@major` to access them (remember that associations also [add a bunch of methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference) to the models to make it easier to use them)

```
# In /app/views/majors/show.html.erb
<div class="row">
  <% @major.reviews.each do |review| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Or more conveniently, you could use a partial (if you want to display the list of reviews in the same way on each page), and use the shortcut for rendering a collection:

```
# /app/views/reviews/_review.html.erb
<div>
  <h3><%= link_to review.review,
    :controller => "reviews", :action => "show", :id => review.id %></h3>
  <small>Posted on <%= review.created_at %> by
    <a href="#"><%= review.user.profile_name %></a></small>
</div>

# In /app/views/majors/show.html.erb
<div class="row">
  <%= render @major.reviews %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Zaid!  This is so helpful!  I am encountering one error: NoMethodError in MajorsController#show undefined method `includes' for #<Major:0x007f8ad3ae56e0>, In my majors_controller.rb file though I have: def show @major = Major.find_by_slug(params[:id]).includes(:reviews => :user) end

Comment: That was my bad, the `.includes()` should come before the `.find()`, so `@major = Major.includes(:reviews => :user).find_by_slug(params[:id])` should work.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to whether these are the appropriate associations, it all depends on what you are trying to achieve and what the relationships actually look like in the 'real' world.

From what it looks like, in your app you have Users, who can each create (or have) many different reviews, you have Majors where each individual major can have many reviews associated with it, and you have Reviews, where each individual review is associated with many different majors (i.e. one review can be written about several different majors).

Is this correct? If so, then the associations you are trying to create seem to be appropriate.

However, I am not sure you are quite there with the implementation.

Review belongs to user, and so it is appropriate that it has user_id column, however it should not have a major_id column (otherwise you are limiting each review to belonging to just one major).

Instead the relationship between Majors and Reviews is managed via a joins table (for example major_reviews) which would then have major_id and review_id columns. Have you created this join table yet?

Once you have the associations correctly setup, you will have access to a number of rails methods to make your life easier when it comes to running queries.

For instance in order to get all the reviews of a given user you can do `@user.reviews`. Similarly to get the related majors for an individual review you can do `@review.majors`, or to get all of the reviews for a given major you can do `@major.reviews`.

You can see further examples of the methods available to `@major`or `@review`in section 4.4.1 of the Rails guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association.

Comment: I actually do want each review to relate to only one major.  It sounds like I might have set it up correctly then.  Thank you!!

Comment: In which case, the has_and_belongs_to_many is probably not appropriate, and as Zaid mentions below you would be better off using has_many and belongs_to for the relationship between Majors and Reviews. Your database schema is already set up for this, but you would need to make the changes in the models.